# Create Modern Page with Page Layout

Tags: office-365, spfx, page-layout, modern-experience

I want to create the Modern SharePoint Page using any Custom Page Layout.

Is it possible using SPFx or server side code? If yes, Can you please share the code or any reference link?

Comment: Did you help my answer? Mark it please.

Answer (score -1):

You are defining alternative layout inside of the modern page.

Check [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages) there is written:

> These customizations are currently not supported for "modern" pages:
>
> - Adding "classic" web parts on "modern" pages Custom CSS via AlternateCSSUrl web property
> - Custom JavaScript embedded via user custom actions (see note on SharePoint Framework Extensions)
> - **Custom master pages (more extensive branding will be supported later using alternative options)**
> - Minimal Download Strategy (MDS)
> - Modern pages inside of the a Site Template package (Save site as a template)